# Javascript keeps adding up a sum on total

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add up some form fields but it doesn't matter the arrays i tried, it keeps adding up the total value if checked again, I would need it to sum the values from the **checkboxes** with the input value from **Amount** only if checked if unchecked value subtracts or doesn't add, Some help is awesomely appreciated.

```
<div class="hire-accessories"><input type="checkbox" name="baby-st" id="baby-st" class="checkbox" value="5"/>Baby Seat 0-2 Year £5(Day)</div>
<div class="hire-accessories"><input type="checkbox" name="child-st" id="child-st" class="checkbox" value="5" />Child Seat 3-7 Year Seat £7(Day)</div>
<div class="hire-accessories"><input type="checkbox" name="gps" id="gps" class="checkbox" value="5" />TomTom GPS</div>
<div class="hire-accessories"><input type="checkbox" name="bike-rack" id="bike-rack" class="checkbox" value="10" />Bike Rack</div>
<div class="hire-accessories"><input type="checkbox" name="mbike" id="mbike" class="checkbox" value="5" />Montainbike</div>

<input type="text" name="Amount" id="Amount" value="20" readonly class="cat_textbox" />
```

And My JS is as follow:

```
var updateTotal = function () { 
    var Amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Amount").value);
    var total = 0;


    total += ($('input[name=baby-st]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=baby-st]:checked').val()) : 0;
    total += ($('input[name=child-st]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=child-st]:checked').val()) : 0;
    total += ($('input[name=gps]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=gps]:checked').val()) : 0;
    total += ($('input[name=bike-rack]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=bike-rack]:checked').val()) : 0;
    total += ($('input[name=mbike]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=mbike]:checked').val()) : 0;

        document.getElementById('Amount').value = Amount+total;

};

$('#baby-st, #child-st, #gps, #bike-rack, #mbike').change(function() {

    if(this.checked)
   {

   }
   updateTotal();

});
```

[THE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/RicardoAlves/q0qqubgg/1/)

Comment: Well once you've added a value, you never "un-add" it. Your code always starts off by checking to see what the *previous* total was. I think if you just forget about "Amount" it'll work a lot better.

Comment: You're always resetting `var Amount`, so the new number is persisted instead. You should really dry up your code too http://stackoverflow.com/a/28618519/1842294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your Amount declaration outside of the updateTotal function.

```
var Amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Amount").value);
var updateTotal = function () { 
    var total = 0;

    total += ($('input[name=baby-st]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=baby-st]:checked').val()) : 0;
    total += ($('input[name=child-st]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=child-st]:checked').val()) : 0;
    total += ($('input[name=gps]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=gps]:checked').val()) : 0;
    total += ($('input[name=bike-rack]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=bike-rack]:checked').val()) : 0;
    total += ($('input[name=mbike]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=mbike]:checked').val()) : 0;

    document.getElementById('Amount').value = Amount+total;

};

$('#baby-st, #child-st, #gps, #bike-rack, #mbike').change(function() {

    if(this.checked)
    {

    }
    updateTotal();

});
```

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/g057fw22/)

Comment: This doesn't work. It has the same problem as the question's demo

Comment: Great Stuff!! I cant believe it was that! Thanks Bro! you're super!

Comment: Ugh. The provided code works. The fiddle link was wrong. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
document.getElementById('Amount').value = Amount+total;
```

to be

```
document.getElementById('Amount').value = total;
```

You're accidentally adding the original `Amount` value along with the `total` when you are updating the value of Amount.

If you want to add something else to the total (surcharge? other purchases? taxes?), you'll need to give us more information before we can tell you the best way to do that. But the general idea will be to store that value in a variable:

```
var otherAmount = 20;
```

and then add it as before:

```
document.getElementById('Amount').value = total + otherAmount;
```

(You can't store that other amount in #Amount.value, which is what you are trying to do.)

Comment: Thanks a try, but.. That way it overwrites the Amount field with a new result from Checkboxes, I need the checkboxes to add to the Amount value and don't keep adding up

Answer (score 0):

It keeps adding because you pull the new amount value here:

```
var Amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Amount").value);
```

If you want to add the sum on top of the original value 20 you have do this:
https://jsfiddle.net/q0qqubgg/2/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your amount variable needs to be extracted from your function so that you don't get the updated value every change event.
Also...... may I suggest that you DRY up and reduce unnecessary code in your example?

```
// Use parseInt everywhere instead of parseFloat. You're not
// supplying floating integers, so no need to parse them as one
var amount = parseInt(document.getElementById("Amount").value);
var updateTotal = function() {
  var total = 0;

  // Loop through the inputs since they all share the same class
  $('.hire-accessories input:checked').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
  });

  document.getElementById('Amount').value = amount + total;

};

// Pass the function directly to the event listener
// the anonymous function and random conditional are unnecessary
$('.hire-accessories input').change(updateTotal);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcks3cna/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/k79ah2d7/

You first need to set your 'var Amount' outside of your function.  Then on change you want to refigure your total from the currently checked boxes, return that value and add it to your original base amount.

```
//Moved this out of the function
var Amount = parseFloat($('#Amount').val());
var updateTotal = function () { 

var total = 0;

total += ($('input[name=baby-st]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=baby-st]:checked').val()) : 0;
total += ($('input[name=child-st]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=child-st]:checked').val()) : 0;
total += ($('input[name=gps]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=gps]:checked').val()) : 0;
total += ($('input[name=bike-rack]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=bike-rack]:checked').val()) : 0;
total += ($('input[name=mbike]:checked').length > 0) ? parseFloat($('input[name=mbike]:checked').val()) : 0;
    //Return your total
    return total;     
};

$('#baby-st, #child-st, #gps, #bike-rack, #mbike').change(function() {

    if(this.checked)
   {



   }
   var total = updateTotal();
   //Reset the amount to display
   $('#Amount').val(Amount+total);

});
```